# Int instance variable not incrementing after method call

Tags: java

Can anyone please tell me why the output is 82 instead of 92?

```
public class practice {
    int squares = 81;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new practice().go();
    }

    void go() {
        incr(++squares);
        System.out.println(squares);
    }

    void incr(int squares) {
        squares += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify primitive types through method arguments. It would be 92 if you did `this.squares += 10;` as opposed to `squares += 10;`

Comment: Java is pass-by-value. Think on that a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `squares` is still 82 is due to the scope. Once the `incr` function is called, `squares` is 82, and then the function gets a local copy of the variable.

The local copy it has, does get incremented by 10, and then goes out of scope at the end of the function. Control then goes back to the `go` function, with the squares that hasn't been incremented by 10.

And then it prints it out.

If you did this:

```
public class practice {

int squares = 81;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new practice().go();
}

void go() {
    incr(++squares);
    System.out.println(squares);
}

void incr(int squares) {
    squares += 10; 
    System.out.println(squares);
}
}
```

You would then see

```
92
82
```

as output.

Comment: As a value type on the stack, it actually does not need to be GC'd.

Answer (score 8):

```
void incr(int squares) {
      squares += 10; 
  }
```

`squares` here in parameter name will hide instance variable . so, `+` happens on parameter variable, not on instance variable.

use `this.squares` if you want operate on instance variable (incr(...) is instance method).

Answer (score 5):

You have pre-incremented `squares` here:

```
incr(++squares);
```

So 82 is passed in to `incr`.  But `incr` receives a copy of the value 82 in its local variable `squares`.  That copy is modified, but the original is not modified.  In `incr`, the name `squares` refers to the local variable, not the instance variable.  So, back in `go`, `squares` is still 82.

To get `92`, all you would have to do is rename the `squares` parameter to any other legal identifier (say, `_squares`, or `square`, or `foo`), so that `squares` in the method's body would refer to the instance variable, and not the parameter.

(There are other ways of course, such as writing `this.squares += 10;` in `incr`, or returning `squares` in `incr` and assigning the result to `squares` in `go`.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't modify the variable after sending it to the method. You call:

```
incr(++squares);
```

which increases 81 by 1 (thus getting 82), THEN sends it to the incr method. That method then updates the parameter it was send by 10, getting 92.

However, this value isn't returned, and as such, the print statement produces 82.

If you put a print statement inside the incr() method, you would get 92.

Answer (score 0):

```
void go() {
     squares++;
     incr(squares);
     System.out.println(squares);
 }
```

Increment squares to get 82 then pass that in as a refreshed integer and it should come out 92.

Comment: At least do some talking. This seems like a silent post.

Answer (score 0):

Since `squeres` is a local variable to `incr` method .So it should be

```
 void go() {
   squares = incr(++squares);
   System.out.println(squares);
 }
 int incr(int squares) { 
    return  (squares += 10);
 }
```

or

```
 void go() {
   incr(++squares);
   System.out.println(squares);
 }
 void incr(int squares) { 
    this.squares = squares + 10;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning your incremented value from `incr` method. If you print out on screen result in that method, you will see it is 92 in it indeed;

Answer (score 0):

The local variable squares is hiding the class variable

```
void incr(int squares) {
    squares += 10;
}
```

You should use

```
void incr(int squares) {
    this.squares += 10;
}
```